# Get superclass input parameter in child class python3

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, parent-child, super

I need some help in understanding below problem in python3.6.
I've 2 classes: parent & child. child inherits parent.
I need to access the variables declared/passed in child within parent class.

But when i run the command :

Command: **child(fmt='abc').test_func()**

Observations:

1. This returns 'X' which is the default value, but i'm expecting 'abc'
   to be returned. -- So the value passed is not working.
2. If i return the variable self.mode within test_func,
   it returns me correct value. -- So the value declared is working.

Note: **kwargs is intended in child class because it needs to accept variable inputs at runtime, which works.

TIA

========================================================================

class parent:

```
def __init__(self, fmt = 'X'):
    self.fmt = fmt
    self.mode = 'abc'
```

========================================================================

class child(parent):

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()   

def test_func(self):
    return self.fmt
```

========================================================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1 -- hand the variable 'abc' to the child

```
child(fmt='abc').test_func()

# this works, the variables goes into the child's __init__ function
```

Step2 -- the child should hand it up to parent

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    # the variable is here
    super().__init__()  
    # but never gets passed or assigned anywhere
```

Step3 -- the parent assigns it

```
def __init__(self, fmt = 'X'):
    # your input of 'abc' never reaches here
    self.fmt = fmt
```

---

Two possible solutions. Either

- [BEST] Delete the child's `__init__` method, now the variable will pass directly to the parent's `__init__` method skipping Step2 entirely.
- Fix the child's `__init__` method, by forwarding any supplied variables (so `super().__init__(**kwargs)`)